# How to make an application and website?

Tags: web, desktop-application

I want to make a chat application in website and desktop application
How can I make that?
Need I use 2 language for that? Like java for app and php for website

Thanks you!!

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code wishing site. See "**[ask]**" for more information on how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure.
`Java` for the desktop application (there a lot more possible languages).
`Php` in the website back-end and `HTML` (and `JavaScript`) for the front-end.

There are two ways to achieve this:
**1**. Peer to peer: the clients connect directly.
**2**. Use a server with, for example, `MySQL` to "connect" the applications.